# Salen signos extraños en mi base de datos

Tags: php, html

Quizás este problema sea un clásico dentro del MYSQL, a mi me pasa lo mismo pero no logro como quitarlos y insertar los datos de forma normal, **ej. "¿Hola cómo estás?**. Espero de su ayuda, gracias amigos.

**Tengo UTF-8 en mi página web (Archivos PHP/HTML) y la base de datos en latin y por último la tabla que en este caso sería 'site_news' está en utf8_general_ci**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que sale en la barra de dirección, la solución más rápida sería quitarle los signos (?,¿,!,¡ etc...) y dejar sólo el nombre y el número de id (ej. 3-nombredeltitulo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando un método de encriptación?

Comment: No, simplemente es texto junto con signos de interrogación e etc. Pero en la página como tal no muestra errores pero en la db sale todos esos signos con 'A'.

Comment: Incluye en la pregunta la salida de `show variables like '%char%';`.